# Is there a way to have platform-specific dependencies in environment.yml?

Tags: python, cross-platform, conda

I'm trying to use Conda to set up build & testing environments for a project ([LensKit](https://github.com/lenskit/lenskit)), and need to have platform-specific dependencies.  Specifically, on Linux builds I need `libgfortran` and `openssl`, but not on Windows.

Is there a way that I can state, in `environment.yml`, that I need `libgfortran` but only on the 32- and 64-bit Linux platforms? Or do I need to have separate environment definitions to cover this case?

The other potential solution I see is creating a dummy package and publishing it to http://anaconda.org that just depends on the required base packages for each platform, and require that package in `environment.yml`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "dummy packages" are actually called "metapackages". See https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-metapackage.html. That seems a good option.

Alternatively, could you build a conda package of your project? In the conda recipe's `meta.yml` you can use selectors for different platforms. https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#preprocessing-selectors

Comment: Thanks.  It'd be awesome if preprocessing selectors would work in `environment.yml` too.

Comment: I think `environment.yml`  is purely meant as an exact dump of an environment. The docs explicitly say it may not work cross-platform. The `meta.yml` is really about installing the exact requirements. We probably need to forget pip and it's way of installing using a requirements file...

Comment: I would also find selectors in `environment.yml` useful, so I filed a feature request at https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8089 .

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled across the same problem and wrote a small parser for exactly this problem. In your case, you could create an *environment.yml.meta* file as follows:

```
name: demo_env
dependencies:
  - <your_other_dependencies>
  - libgfortran [platform startswith linux]
  - openssl     [platform startswith linux]
```

and then create the environment from it with

```
python create_env.py
```

It's of course not the same as if it was supported native, because you need to either add the parser as submodule to your repo or just copy it over, but maybe you find it useful. The project is on GitHub:

https://github.com/silvanmelchior/cme_parser

Answer (score 4):

[`conda-lock`](https://github.com/conda/conda-lock) now supports [processing selectors](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#preprocessing-selectors) in `environment.yml` files (added in [version 1.3.0](https://github.com/conda/conda-lock/releases/tag/v1.3.0)).

So if you have an `environment.yml` file like this (notice the `# [not osx]` selector):

```yaml
name: python-project
channels:
  - nvidia
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.10.*
  - pip # pip must be mentioned explicitly, or conda-lock will fail
  - pytorch-cuda=11.8 # [not osx]
```

When you run `conda-lock -k explicit`, the selector will make sure that the `pytorch-cuda` dependency is not written in the lock file for Mac OSX. You can then run `conda update --file conda-<linux/osx/win>-64.lock` to update the dependencies in your environment.

At the time of writing this, while locking the dependencies, `conda-lock` still shows a warning:

> WARNING:conda_lock.src_parser.selectors:filtered out line   `- pytorch-cuda=11.8 # [not osx]` due to unmatchable selector

However, it successfully generates the lock file for Windows/Linux with `pytorch-cuda` and for OSX without `pytorch-cuda`.

This is for a Pytorch CUDA issue I recently had, but it should work the same for your dependencies.